# Azure FrontDoor Http->HTTPS

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

everyone!
I have own service working only by HTTP which set up as a backend in Azure FrontDoor.
If I want to use my service with HTTPS I may use Azure AppGateway - which allows to me to use ssl-termination.
Is Azure FrontDoor allows do the same?

For now I have next configuration:
Service on port 8443

Configured FrontDoor:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp2V1.png)

And attached custom domain with cert (letsEncrypt)

So that, when I going to http - I retrieve [200 OK responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Qg3.png)

But, when I use HTTPS - I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baSiE.png)

So, does AFD allow to cover HTTP by HTTPS?

Thanks a lot!

UPD: Route config
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P5PM.png)
[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jd8G.png)

Comment: what is your routing config looking like?

Comment: I have only root  (/*)

Comment: There is a lot more to your routing config. Please share that too

Comment: added into question body

Comment: Got it. Answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend is apparently only configured to listen to HTTP (on port 8443). From your config, it does not look like your backend would support HTTPS. So in order for this to work, you can change your routing configuration:

Forwarding Protocol: HTTP (instead of "match incoming")

This way, Front Door will always talk HTTP to the backend, even if the incoming client request was on HTTPS.

Note: Generally I would still recommend to use HTTPS between Front Door and your backend, since this can be quite a long network path, even though it all stays on the Microsoft backbone, most people prefer to have encrypted traffic there, too.